# Having a trouble with reveal on scroll js

Tags: javascript, html

So I included wow.js in my code to reveal elements on scroll and now when I scroll to the last section of my page [this](http://image.prntscr.com/image/dcd6fc5836aa4b978ff7ef5b60f82c04.png) appears, so far I've tried to make things disappear when I moved away from them but couldn't find such function in wow.js so I though maybe someone here can help me. I also have sticky.js for navbar to follow user down the site.

This is the code for  review  houses, minus the picture and stars since the picture is on my HD and stars are font-awesome.

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
 color: #242424;
 font-style: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 14px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
 color: #141414;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 14px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Review houses */

.rev-houses {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#first-house {
  left: 160px;
}
.house-one-text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #191919;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.house-one-text-name {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #191919;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400i|Open+Sans:400|Roboto+Condensed:700|Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Font awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Scroll CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">

  <!-- Scroll script -->
  <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    new WOW().init();
  </script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="100">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-toggle="collapse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Online Shop</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about-link" class="navbar-about">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#review-link" class="navbar-contact">Reviews</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#shops-link" class="navbar-contact">Shops</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/" class="navbar-contact">Order Now</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>

    <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-offset="100">
      <div class="review-houses">
        <div id="first-house" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 rev-houses">
          <div class="text-center">
          </div>
          <p class="text-center house-one-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <br>
          <div class="text-left">
            <p class="house-one-text-name">- John Doe</p>
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center">
            <div class="review-stars">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First, thanks for formatting your question is a way that is well-laid out. Second, a bit of clarification. The problem is that your reviews overlap your header when your `wow()` code is triggered? `wow.js` does nothing without a function that calls it -- assuming you wrote a function to use it, could you please update your question so that it includes your `wow()` code as well? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I added the wow script at the head and also a div to call it in my snippet above. But I'm starting to think it has nothing to do with wow.js since I've tried disabling it and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've narrowed down your problem :) Can you please include the code to reproduce the header as well? I can't be sure of what the problem is without knowing the exact code causing it ;) Having said that, it sounds like you would either need to use `clear: both` on your header, or give it a higher `z-index` than your content. If you could update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would be very much appreciated. Creating a JSFiddle, BootPly or similar would help too :)

Comment: You'll need to provide the `navbar` code for me to work out the z-index issue, but I'm guessing just CSS of `.navbar {z-index: 1}` should fix the problem. Also, `z-index` has a default of 0 :)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, I've edited the OP with the navbar code (it's just a bootstrap navbar code nothing special) and also all the CSS regarding navbar.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle using your code, and was unable to re-produce the problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/64kaf9xp/. Please update your code so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `verifiable` part of that means that your code can be copied (without requiring any extra code) to demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: Alright, so I got rid of all the code I'm sure it's not causing the problem and you can see the problem yourself here: https://jsfiddle.net/64kaf9xp/2/ . Keep in mind I put the picture and about text just so you can scroll down since the problem occurs only on those review boxes when they are scrolled over.

Comment: I don't know if you've got  my reply from 2 days ago. I still haven't figured out how to fix the problem..